# How can I get all filenames without path in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/GalleryImage/" + v));
foreach (string item in filePaths)
{
    Response.Write(item);
}
```

Problem in this code i am getting file name with full path like this

```
C:\Users\AGENTJ.AGENTJ-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\mfaridalam\Gallery\GalleryImage\c050\DSC_0865.JPG
```

I just want file which is "DSC_0865.JPG"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method to get the file name (and extension) of the specified path, without the directory:

```
foreach (string item in filePaths)
{
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(item);
     Response.Write(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/GalleryImage/" + v))
         .Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it gave me error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @JayZee If you require it to be an array, pop on `ToArray`, else just change the type of `filePaths` to `IEnumerable<string>.`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/GalleryImage/" + v));
foreach (string item in filePaths)
{
    Response.Write(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the methods in the `Path` such as `GetFileName` if you just want the bit without the path.

In your case something like:

```
foreach(string item in filePaths)
{
      Response.Write(Path.GetFileName(item));
}
```